# How can I use python to insert text from one file to another in various lines?

Tags: python, variables, text, replace

I am totally new to python, and I have the following question. I have searched quite a bit and while I can find similar questions with answers, I can't find one that addresses the variable nature of mine. So here goes:
I have a file that in several places (hundreds) has a line that reads <text = " ">
I want to replace each of these lines with lines from a different file in sequential order.
Let's say that file reads like this:
"abcdefg",  "hijklmn" and so on.
I want the first instance of <text = " "> to be replaced by "abcdefg", the second by "hijklmn" and so forth.
Thank you

Comment: What code have you tried? Can you be more specific about the examples? Give a sample of each file category that you use and what you want your output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified if the result must be in another file, but I assumed so.

Assuming that `foo.txt` is the file containing the patter to match (that is `<text = " ">`), and `replacements.txt` contains the replacements to put, line by line, this is how to do this task.

```py
import re

with open('foo.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

with open('replacements.txt') as f:
    replacements = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

First we read the contents of the files (stripping every line from whitespaces and endline character).

```py
j = 0
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    result = re.match('<text = " ">', line)
    if result and j < len(replacements):
        lines[i] = replacements[j]
        j += 1
```

Then we setup a counter for the replacements array, and for every line we search the string to replace.

If it's found and we have replacements to put, we proceed to change that line with the j-th element.

```py
lines = [line + '\n' for line in lines]

with open('foo_modified.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Then we join together the modified lines (adding manually the endline character, stripped before), and we write it out in another file.

Answer (score 0):

As @amquack commented and SO guidelines request, you should have an example of code you tried posted here or at least complete info about the files you want. You should edit the question with more complete information even if you get a good answer and accept it here.

As I read your question you have a file, say `f1`, that looks like

```sh
a
bunch
<text = " ">
of
<text = " ">
other
lines
<text = " ">
```

and another file `f2` that looks like this

```
string1
string2
string3
```

and you want to replace the lines in `f1` that read `<text = " ">` with lines from `f2`. Here's one possibility that assumes `f2` contains the same number of lines as there are `<text = " ">` lines in `f1`

```py
# get the contents of your files using the with statement so
# the interpreter cleans up after you
with open('f1', 'r') as infile:
    f1_lines = infile.readlines()

with open('f2', 'r') as infile:
    f2_lines = infile.readlines()

# create a new file for output
with open('out', 'w') as outfile:
    # loop over the lines in the text you want to modify
    for line in f1_lines:
        if line.strip() == '<text = " ">':
            # this is a line you want to replace, so pop the next 
            # line you want to insert off of f2_lines and write
            # it to the output file
            outfile.write(f2_lines.pop(0))
            if len(f2_lines) == 0:
                # if that was the last line to insert, add a newline
                # character in case there are more lines to copy over
                # from f1
                outfile.write('\n')
        else:
            # the text you want to replace is not in this line, so
            # copy this line to the output file
            outfile.write(line)
```

Note that a for loop and `f2_lines.pop` will not perform as well as other methods if you have very large files or you're running this code on a large number of files. The file contents and code above produce a file that looks like this

```sh
a
bunch
string1
of
string2
other
lines
string3
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly. I apologize for not following the proper protocol, I just did not know where to start, that's how little I know. So double thank you for for taking the time to understand my question and to answer it.